# Tabulator - clear the contents of the cell, before editing

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator JavaScript library. In that, I want to clear contents of an editable cell, when the user clicks on the editable cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use a custom editor to achieve this, below is a version of the input editor without the value assignment:

```
var inputEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

        //create and style input
        var cellValue = cell.getValue(),
        input = document.createElement("input");

        input.setAttribute("type", "text");

        input.style.padding = "4px";
        input.style.width = "100%";
        input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

        input.value = "";

        onRendered(function(){
            input.focus();
            input.style.height = "100%";
        });

        function onChange(e){
            if(((cellValue === null || typeof cellValue === "undefined") && input.value !== "") || input.value != cellValue){
                success(input.value);
            }else{
                cancel();
            }
        }

        //submit new value on blur or change
        input.addEventListener("change", onChange);
        input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

        //submit new value on enter
        input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case 13:
                success(input.value);
                break;

                case 27:
                cancel();
                break;
            }
        });

        return input;
}
```

You can then assign the editor to a column in its column definition:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:inputEditor}
```